# How to merge two dataframes in Apache Spark without common key?

Tags: python, apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I am trying to join two dataframes.

data: DataFrame[_1: bigint, _2: vector]

cluster: DataFrame[cluster: bigint]

```
result = data.join(broadcast(cluster))
```

The strange thing is, that all the executors are failing on the joining step.

I have no idea what I could do.

The data file is 2.8 gb on HDFS and the cluster data only 5 mb.
The files are read using Parquet.

Comment: Could you post the exact error you get?

Comment: The exact error was that executors were failing. No clear could be found. I know the answer now :)

Answer (score 1):

What does work is this:

```
data = sqlContext.read.parquet(data_path)
data = data.withColumn("id", monotonicallyIncreasingId())

cluster = sqlContext.read.parquet(cluster_path)  
cluster = cluster.withColumn("id", monotonicallyIncreasingId())

result = data.join(cluster, on="id")
```

Adding the cluster DataFrame directly to the data DataFrame with:

```
data.withColumn("cluster", cluster.cluster)
```

Does not work.

```
data.join(cluster)
```

Also does not work, executors are failing whilst having enough memory.

No idea why it wasn't working...